# Will many parameters in a recursive function cause performance issues?

Tags: c++, c++11

My code will traverse around in a binary tree in a recursive fashion. Doing this I have some parameters I need to control. Thus, my function looks like this:

```
FindPoints(int leftchild, int rightchild, int ly_index, int uy_index, int bit, int nodepos, int amount, int level);
```

It is called a lot of times. Will the performance of my program take a hit because of the amount of parameters?

Comment: Well, it will obviously take longer than if you had fewer - unless the parameters happen to map to the same registers in the caller and callee (not likely). But aren't those parameters necessary for your function to work correctly?

Comment: What about defining a struct and passing it by reference?

Comment: @PaoloM Which impact will that have on the performance? I am sincerely interested :)

Comment: @Mads Tomorrow I'll do a bit of benchmarking for you, now I'm using the smartphone... What a geek ;)

Comment: @PaoloM, you can't do that.  It defeats the whole purpose of making it a recursive function.

Comment: Performance is not the primary concern with recursion, but *Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Performance would more strongly depend on if the function uses tail end recursion or not. In which case the compiler could just optimize and turn into a loop. I guess you could cache miss a bunch, so the below advice for using a struct is good.

Comment: @PaoloM - Although I'll say that would be significantly CLEANER, there's no way that it's more efficient.  You're using up memory for each of the values, then using up more memory for the structure itself.  The impact is probably relatively minimal, unless it's being used in a tight loop for several thousand runs, but it still exists.

Comment: @user2366842 For performance, look at my answer at this question. Furthermore, I don't think that memory consumption will be higher with a struct passed by ref. At every recursion step, you add a pointer to the stack instead of ten ints.

Comment: We need more information. Does each recursive call change the value of most of the parameters? Or perhaps you just change `leftchild` and `rightchild`, and the are passed on unchanged? And also, how many recursive calls are made within each call? I guess each call typically results in two calls, one for each child - is that correct?  Maybe the question should be edited accordingly. If you can't use tail recursion, and if most values are changing, then you have little option but to use the current solution.

Answer (score 10):

The process during recursion is:

1. Allocate space for parameters on the stack.  Usually subtracting a value from the stack pointer register.
2. Copy variable values onto the stack.  Depends on the objects or
   values.
3. Call function.  This may cause a flush of the processor's
   instruction cache.
4. At end of function, stack pointer is restored by adding a
   value.
5. Return from function call; may cause flush to instruction cache.

The general concern is not performance, but recursion depth and stack size.  Recursion that goes beyond the limitations of the stack is called a **Stack Overflow** defect.

An iterative solution may be faster because the compiler may be able to optimize the loop.  Optimizing recursive calls is more difficult for a compiler to optimize.

By the way, on modern processors, the worst case timing of a recursive call is less than 1 millisecond, usually around nanosecond resolution.  So you are trying to squeeze nanoseconds out of a program.  Not very good Return On Investment (ROI).

Answer (score 5):

Performance depends on many factors; ideally you would try one way, try the other and compare. However, here are some general considerations that may help you get a feel of what is going on:

- If your function does much work, time wasted on function calls will not be significant.
- If your function mostly passes parameters unchanged, you should definitely think about refactoring your code. If it calls itself with all (or almost all) parameters having different values, you cannot improve your code - it's too complex.
- Function call performance depends on calling convention. Compilers typically pass the first few parameters in registers (very fast), and the rest on stack (slower). You might want to make the number of parameters small (2 for `fastcall`; 4 for `ARM` convention - just two examples that I know), such that they all fit into registers.

To expand on second point - if your function doesn't change most of its parameters, each call will copy these parameters around the stack - this is absolutely useless work for the computer. In addition to wasting time, it also wastes space in data cache (leading to more slowdown, which is particularly nasty because it cannot even be attributed to any code in particular) and might cause stack overflow (or maybe not, depending on your OS).

One way to improve your code in this situation is: using a `struct` that holds all unchanged parameters, and passing a pointer/reference to it:

```
struct DataForFindPoints
{
    int ly_index;
    int uy_index;
    int bit;
    int nodepos;
    int amount;
    int level;
};

FindPoints(int leftchild, int rightchild, const DataForFindPoints& data);
```

Or (object-oriented way): make a `class` that has `FindPoints` as a member function, and all unchanged parameters as fields.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**

Under Windows, compiling with Visual Studio 2010 in release mode targeting x64 platform, **passing unwrapped arguments is far slower** than passing a single struct by reference or even by value.

Results follow:

```
Multi result = 0; multi iterations = 10000
Ref result = 0; ref iterations = 10000
Value result = 0; value iterations = 10000

---------------------------------------------------
Timer "multi args":
Total time = 0.387886

------------------------------------------
Timer "struct by reference":
Total time = 0.0679177

------------------------------------------
Timer "struct by value":
Total time = 0.143382
```

**An observation**

The more your function does calculations in its body, the less the copy overhead will hurt performance. In fact, I've benchmarked a function that performs just some additions and one division.

**Some details now**

I've defined a struct containing all your parameters

```
struct Args{
    int leftchild;
    int rightchild;
    int ly_index;
    int uy_index;
    int bit;
    int nodepos;
    int amount;
    int level;

    Args(int l, int r, int ly, int uy, int b, int n, int a, int lev)
        : leftchild(l)
        , rightchild(r)
        , ly_index(ly)
        , uy_index(uy)
        , bit(b)
        , nodepos(n)
        , amount(a)
        , level(lev)
    {}
};
```

and 3 functions.

```
static size_t counter1 = 0;
static size_t counter2 = 0;
static size_t counter3 = 0;

int FindPoints(int leftchild, int rightchild, int ly_index, int uy_index, int bit, int nodepos, int amount, int level)
{
    ++counter1;
    leftchild = leftchild + (rightchild + ly_index + uy_index + bit + nodepos + amount + level) / 100 - 1;
    return leftchild ? FindPoints( leftchild, rightchild, ly_index, uy_index, bit, nodepos, amount, level) : 0;
}

int FindPointsRef( Args& a )
{
    ++counter2;
    a.leftchild = a.leftchild + (a.rightchild + a.ly_index + a.uy_index + a.bit + a.nodepos + a.amount + a.level) / 100 - 1;
    return a.leftchild ? FindPointsRef( a ) : 0;
}

int FindPointsValue( Args a )
{
    ++counter3;
    a.leftchild = a.leftchild + (a.rightchild + a.ly_index + a.uy_index + a.bit + a.nodepos + a.amount + a.level) / 100 - 1;
    return a.leftchild ? FindPointsValue( a ) : 0;
}
```

They all do the same job, but the first takes **arguments as in your question**, the second takes the **struct of arguments by reference** and the third takes the **struct by value**.

I've built the program using Visual Studio 2010, release x64 configuration, and I've measured using a home made class that just wrap the Windows function `QueryPerformanceCounter` and provides a convenient output operator.

The main function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    // define my timers
    PersistentTimer timer_multi("multi args");
    PersistentTimer timer_ref("struct by reference");
    PersistentTimer timer_value("struct by value");

    int leftchild = 10000;  // number of iterations; 10000 to prevent stack overflow
    int rightchild = 1;     // sum of other values is < 100 (look to FindPoints* implementations)
    int ly_index = 2;
    int uy_index = 3;
    int bit = 4;
    int nodepos = 5;
    int amount = 6;
    int level = 7;

    // define structs of arguments for second and third function
    Args args_ref( leftchild, rightchild, ly_index, uy_index, bit, nodepos, amount, level );
    Args args_copy( leftchild, rightchild, ly_index, uy_index, bit, nodepos, amount, level );

    // return values initialized to a non zero value just to be sure that functions have done thir job
    int a1 = 5;
    timer_multi.measure([&]{
        a1 = FindPoints( leftchild, rightchild, ly_index, uy_index, bit, nodepos, amount, level );
    });
    std::cout << "Multi result = " << a1 << "; multi iterations = " << counter1 << '\n';

    int a2 = 5;
    timer_ref.measure([&]{
        a2 = FindPointsRef( args_ref );
    });
    std::cout << "Ref result = " << a2 << "; ref iterations = " << counter2  << '\n';

    int a3 = 5;
    timer_value.measure([&]{
        a3 = FindPointsValue( args_copy );
    });
    std::cout << "Value result = " << a3 << "; value iterations = " << counter3  << '\n';

    // print timer results
    std::cout << timer_multi << timer_ref << timer_value;

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Do you have compiler optimizations? That code doesn't work for me, give me stack overflow in FindPointRef cause he do 54000 recursive calls. Only works if i active compiler optimizations

Comment: @amchacon Yes, I do have compiler optimizations turned on. But on VS2010, it works in Debug mode too.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't have significative impact in the perfomance. Its not important. If you need extreme performance, you should do in iterative

But, it's a dirty code. You should try encapsulate arguments in structs or class. Its safer and easier of maintain

Comment: Basing on my benchmark, it hurts performance a lot. On what basis are you stating the contrary?